# table formatting

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, longtable, tabularx

I have a very long list (900 rows) with seven columns reporting the value of a measured magnitude and the errors. I justified to the right all the text in the columns to put more stetic the table, but there's one of the columns that either the magnitude or the error have different number of digits, like for example

```
150.20 $\pm$ 10.00\\ 
402.71 $\pm$ 103.12\\
15.04 $\pm$ 4.59\\
```

and so on, where `$\pm$` is the plus minus sign +-. When I compile the `.tex` it appears kind of a mess, the `$\pm$` signs are not aligned within the column. I would like to format that column in such a way that the errors (the numbers after `$\pm$`) get justified by the right, all the `$\pm$` signs are aligned in the column and the magnitudes (the numbers before `$\pm$`) justified to the right as well, in order to preserve the stetic.

Is there a specific command in latex to use in the `tabular` environment that can do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Try package [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to align the numbers or use two columns with the ± be part of the column separator. And note that a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help us to help you.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can use decimal aligned columns

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{D..{3.2}@ { $\pm$ }D..{3.2}}
150.20 & 10.00\\ 
402.71 & 103.12\\
15.04 & 4.59\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```